# Dependency injection error TSED unit test service

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, express, mocha.js

I'm currently writing tests for a TSED project (express), and whenever I invoke a service using dependency injection in one file I get an error that a service is undefined in a completely different part of the project. Mind you all the code in all other non-test files work properly.

**DBConnectorService.ts** handles all queries to the DB.

```
import { Service, Scope, ProviderScope } from "@tsed/di";
import { Pool } from "pg";
import { GLOBAL_DB_POOL } from "../server";

@Service()
export class DBConnectorService {
    private pool: Pool;

    constructor() {
        this.pool = GLOBAL_DB_POOL;
    }

    executeQuery(query) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.pool.query(query, (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                resolve(results.rows);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**DBConnectorService.spec.ts** handles the tests for the file above.

```
import { DBConnectorService } from "./../../../src/services";
import { inject } from '@tsed/testing';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('DBConnectorService', () => {
    it('should be an instance', () => {
        const dbConnectorService = new DBConnectorService();
        expect(dbConnectorService).to.be.an.instanceof(DBConnectorService);
    });
});
```

When this test is run the output is:

```
❯ npm run test:unit

  DBConnectorService
    ✓ should be an instance

  1 passing (4ms)
```

This is great, it works as it should. However when I change the way the service is implemented in the test from an instantiation to an injection like so:

```
import { DBConnectorService } from "./../../../src/services";
import { inject } from '@tsed/testing';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('DBConnectorService', () => {
    it('should be an instance', inject([DBConnectorService], (dbConnectorService: DBConnectorService) => {
        expect(dbConnectorService).to.be.an.instanceof(DBConnectorService);
    }));
});
```

and run the test again I get the following error:

```
❯ npm run test:unit

  1 failing (31ms)

  1) DBConnectorService
       should be an instance:
     INJECTION_ERROR: Injection failed on FormatCtrl
Origin: Unable to inject dependency. Given token is undefined. Have you enabled emitDecoratorMetadata in your tsconfig.json or decorated your class with @Injectable, @Service, ... decorator ?

FormatCtrl->constructor(formatService: undefined)
                        ^‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
      at Function.throwInjectorError (node_modules/@tsed/di/src/errors/InjectionError.ts:43:11)
      at Map.resolve (node_modules/@tsed/di/src/services/InjectorService.ts:526:22)
      at Map.invoke (node_modules/@tsed/di/src/services/InjectorService.ts:194:38)
      at Map.loadSync (node_modules/@tsed/di/src/services/InjectorService.ts:249:16)
      at Map.<anonymous> (node_modules/@tsed/di/src/services/InjectorService.ts:277:19)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:107:62)
```

This makes no sense at all because the file **FormatCtrl.ts**:

```
import { Controller, Get } from "@tsed/common";
import { FormatService } from "../services";

@Controller('/formats')
export class FormatCtrl {
    constructor(private formatService: FormatService) { }

    @Get('/')
    findAll() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.formatService.findAll().then(resolve);
        });
    }
}
```

uses **FormatService.ts**:

```
import { Service } from '@tsed/di';
import { DBConnectorService } from './DBConnectorService';

@Service()
export class FormatService {
    constructor(private dbConnectorService: DBConnectorService) { }

    findAll() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.dbConnectorService.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM formats').then(resolve);
        });
    }
}
```

which simply uses the **DBConnectorService**

Something even stranger is that if I define the exact same test twice then this happens:

**DBConnectorService.spec.ts**

```
import { DBConnectorService } from "./../../../src/services";
import { inject } from '@tsed/testing';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('DBConnectorService', () => {
    it('should be an instance 1', inject([DBConnectorService], (dbConnectorService: DBConnectorService) => {
        expect(dbConnectorService).to.be.an.instanceof(DBConnectorService);
    }));
    it('should be an instance 2', inject([DBConnectorService], (dbConnectorService: DBConnectorService) => {
        expect(dbConnectorService).to.be.an.instanceof(DBConnectorService);
    }));
});
```

output:

```
❯ npm run test:unit

  DBConnectorService
    1) should be an instance 1
    ✓ should be an instance 2

  1 passing (32ms)
  1 failing

  1) DBConnectorService
       should be an instance 1:
     INJECTION_ERROR: Injection failed on FormatCtrl
Origin: Unable to inject dependency. Given token is undefined. Have you enabled emitDecoratorMetadata in your tsconfig.json or decorated your class with @Injectable, @Service, ... decorator ?

FormatCtrl->constructor(formatService: undefined)
                        ^‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
      at Function.throwInjectorError (node_modules/@tsed/di/src/errors/InjectionError.ts:43:11)
      at Map.resolve (node_modules/@tsed/di/src/services/InjectorService.ts:526:22)
      at Map.invoke (node_modules/@tsed/di/src/services/InjectorService.ts:194:38)
      at Map.loadSync (node_modules/@tsed/di/src/services/InjectorService.ts:249:16)
      at Map.<anonymous> (node_modules/@tsed/di/src/services/InjectorService.ts:277:19)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:107:62)
```

So the first time I try to use injection it fails, but afterwards if I use it again in the same file it magically works. It works even if I implement the exact same test a third time. Does anybody know what's going on here?

Here are my config files

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "back-end",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "rimraf '{src,test}/**/*.{js,js.map}'",
        "build": "yarn tsc",
        "test": "yarn clean && yarn test:lint && yarn test:coverage",
        "test:unit": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha",
        "test:coverage": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc mocha",
        "test:lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
        "test:lint:fix": "tslint --project tsconfig.json --fix",
        "travis:deploy-once": "travis-deploy-once",
        "travis:coveralls": "nyc report --reporter=text-lcov | coveralls",
        "tsc": "tsc --project tsconfig.json",
        "tsc:w": "tsc --project tsconfig.json -w",
        "start": "nodemon --watch \"src/**/*.ts\" --ignore \"node_modules/**/*\" --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
        "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js",
        "docker:build": "yarn build && docker-compose build",
        "deploy": "exit 0"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@tsed/common": "5.42.1",
        "@tsed/core": "5.42.1",
        "@tsed/di": "5.42.1",
        "@tsed/multipartfiles": "^5.42.1",
        "@tsed/swagger": "5.42.1",
        "@tsed/testing": "5.42.1",
        "body-parser": "1.19.0",
        "compression": "1.7.4",
        "concurrently": "5.0.0",
        "cookie-parser": "1.4.4",
        "cors": "2.8.5",
        "cross-env": "6.0.3",
        "express": "4.17.1",
        "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
        "jimp": "^0.9.3",
        "method-override": "^3.0.0",
        "node-uuid": "1.4.8",
        "pg": "^7.18.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/chai": "4.2.5",
        "@types/chai-as-promised": "7.1.2",
        "@types/cors": "2.8.6",
        "@types/express": "4.17.2",
        "@types/fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.14",
        "@types/http-proxy": "1.17.2",
        "@types/mocha": "5.2.7",
        "@types/multer": "^1.4.2",
        "@types/node": "12.12.9",
        "@types/pg": "^7.14.1",
        "@types/request-promise": "4.1.45",
        "@types/sinon": "7.5.0",
        "@types/sinon-chai": "3.2.3",
        "@types/supertest": "2.0.8",
        "@types/swagger-schema-official": "^2.0.20",
        "@types/uuid": "^3.4.7",
        "chai": "4.2.0",
        "chai-as-promised": "7.1.1",
        "concurrently": "5.0.0",
        "mocha": "6.2.2",
        "nodemon": "1.19.4",
        "nyc": "14.1.1",
        "rimraf": "3.0.0",
        "sinon": "7.5.0",
        "sinon-chai": "3.3.0",
        "supertest": "4.0.2",
        "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
        "tslint": "5.20.1",
        "typescript": "3.7.5"
    }
}
```

**mocha.opts**

```
--require node_modules/ts-node/register
{src,test}/**/*.spec.ts
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "target": "ES2016",
        "lib": [
            "ES2016",
            "DOM"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "isolatedModules": false
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./public",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

Also something noteworthy is that I created the project by following the steps here: https://tsed.io/getting-started.html

Comment: Hello from the future.  Any progress on this?

Comment: @c1moore Howdy there. So far none sadly. I basically gave up on this problem because I just couldn't figure out what caused it. I guess there was just some bug in the way testing is handled in TSED. Mind you this problem occured with TSED at version 5.42.1. The latest version is 6.10.3 and perhaps the problem has been fixed by now. If you're building a REST API using NodeJS and want to write tests then maybe the testing component of TSED should be ignored completely and the tests should be implemented in another way.

Answer (score 1):

For the first test :

```
const dbConnectorService = new DBConnectorService();
expect(dbConnectorService).to.be.an.instanceof(DBConnectorService);
```

It works because you create a new instance.

The second one

```
it('should be an instance', inject([DBConnectorService], (dbConnectorService: DBConnectorService) => {
    expect(dbConnectorService).to.be.an.instanceof(DBConnectorService);
}));
```

It fails because you try to inject a service but nothing is instantiate

### Solution

You should use `beforeEach(PlatformTest.bootstrap(Server));` or `beforeEach(PlatformTest.create);`
This code will create a new context and inject all services.

Then you can use your service with two commands :

- `const service = PlatformTest.get<MyService>(MyService);`
- ````
  beforeEach(PlatformTest.create);
  ... // Inside your test
  const locals = [
     {
       token: DbService,
       use: {
         getData: () => {
           return "test";
         }
       }
     }
   ];
   const instance: MyService= await PlatformTest.invoke(MyService, locals);```
  ````

The first one get the service as injected in the platform.
The second one get the service with mocking DI.

See [the documentation](https://tsed.io/docs/testing.html#unit-test) for more info.

### In your case

The code should be something like this :

```
import { DBConnectorService } from "./../../../src/services";
import { inject } from '@tsed/testing';
import { expect } from 'chai';


describe('DBConnectorService', () => {
    beforeEach(PlatformTest.create);
    it('should be an instance', async () => {
        const dbConnectorService= await PlatformTest.get<DBConnectorService>(DBConnectorService);
        expect(dbConnectorService).to.be.an.instanceof(DBConnectorService);
    }));
});
```

Hope it helps